# How can I get the step result in AfterStep hook of cucumber.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cucumber, cucumberjs

As the title says, how can I find the result of a step in the AfterStep hook of cucumber.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the question is about Cucumber.js 1.3x, which is pretty old. In Cucumber.js 3.x, there is no AfterStep hook, instead, there is a function called "setDefinitionFunctionWrapper", which can wrap a step definition, which you have chance to get the step defintion return result and manipulate it.

Here is the documentation on [setDefinitionFunctionWrapper](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/support_files/step_definitions.md)

Answer (score 1):

This thread is old and has an accepted answer, but since this one is outdated, I'll leave this update.
Per [Cucumber version 7.3.2](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/releases/tag/v7.3.2), there is indeed an `AfterStep` Hook. More information about Hooks (such as that one) can be found in [Hooks documentation](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/main/docs/support_files/hooks.md).
There is an example there about what OP queried but will share my own as well:

```
AfterStep(async function (step) {
    console.log(`Step status: ${step.result.status}`);
    if(step.result.status === Status.FAILED) {
        // do something
    } else if(step.result.status === Status.PASSED) {
        // do something else
    }
});
```

Comment: Live example: https://testjam.io/?p=nqXySVV5wS2xWyOpQZLw